# Trying to append to table created with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to append to a table created using the following template via Backbone:

```
<script type='text/template' id='production-budget-template'>
        <table class='table striped'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task ID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Projected Budget</th>
                    <th>Actual Spend</th>
                    <th>Delta Spend</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% _.each(budgetList, function(todo) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="<%= todo.get('statusCheck') %>"><%= todo.get('taskID')%></td>
                        <td class="<%= todo.get('statusCheck') %>"><%= todo.get('description')%></td>
                        <td class="<%= todo.get('statusCheck') %>"><%= todo.get('budget')%></td>
                        <td><%= todo.get('actualSpend')%></td>
                        <td><%= todo.get('actualSpend') =='0' ? '0' : todo.get('actualSpend') - todo.get('budget') %>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </script>
```

I am currently iterating through the collection to create some "delta" and sum values for different columns, and want to append them to the table to display the values inline with the existing template, in the same format. Here is the iterator:

```
var totalActual = 0;
var totalDelta = 0;
var totalProjected = 0;

var budgetLister = new BudgetList();
budgetLister.fetch({
    success: function(){
    _.each(budgetLister.toJSON(), function(budgetItem){
        totalProjected += parseInt(budgetItem['budget']);
        totalActual += parseInt(budgetItem['actualSpend']);
        totalDelta += (parseInt(budgetItem['actualSpend']) == 0 ? 0 : (parseInt(budgetItem['actualSpend']) - parseInt(budgetItem['budget'])));
    });
    }
});
```

How would I add this as a new row with the new values as the new data to the table after it is created? I have tried to use a simple jQuery append to the el, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could approach this.

You said that you tried "a simple jQuery append to the el, but this doesn't work". You didn't include your Backbone view in your code samples, but Backbone views either manage an existing element (rendering directly into it) or create a new element (that you can use as you like). Either way, your table is not the element managed by the view. Thus, something like `this.$el.append(total_tr)` isn't going to work - it's appending your new `<tr>` to the container. That's not going to be your `<table>` element, so I'd expect some weird behaviour.

You could construct a new `<tr>` and append it  by using a jQuery selector with `this.el` as a context:

```
$('table', this.el).append("<tr><td>My</td><td>New</td><td>Row</td></tr>");
```

For instance, if you knew that there was only going to be one table within the element managed by your Backbone view, you might make your render method something like this:

```
BudgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div#production-budget-container',
    template: _.template($('#production-budget-template').html()),
    render: function() { 
        this.$el.html(this.template({budgetList: this.collection})); // Render the template without totals. 

        // Calculate totals here 

        var totalRow = "<tr><td>" + totalProjected + "</td><td>" + totalActual + "</td><td>" + totalDelta + "</td></tr>";
        $('table', this.el).append(totalRow);
        return this; // Backbone convention
    },
});
```

---

Another approach is to calculate your totals directly in your template. Underscore templates can contain arbitrary JavaScript, so you can write something like this:

```
<script type='text/template' id='production-budget-template'>
    <table class='table striped'> 
        <!-- thead omitted for brevity --> 
        <tbody>
            <% var totalProjected = 0; var totalActual = 0; var totalDelta = 0; %>
            <% _.each(budgetList, function(todo) { %>
                <% totalProjected += parseInt(todo.get('budget')) %>
                <% totalActual += parseInt(todo.get('actualSpend')) %>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Rendering the actual todo data omitted for brevity -->
                </tr>
            <% }); %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= totalProjected %></td>
                <td><%= totalActual %></td>
                <td><%= totalDelta %></td>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
    </table>
</script>
```

---

Finally, as a stylistic/encapsulation note, I'd move the `parseInt` and calculations to helper functions on your Backbone model, so you can simply call `todo.getTotalDelta()` in your templates/iterators. They'll be easier to read that way.

Comment: Great thanks! I see now why I was having issues. This helps a lot.